# Какие плюсы и минусы использования goto?

Tags: c++, циклы, goto

Предположим, у меня есть следующая конструкция:

```
while(true) {
    for(;;) {
        //операции
        goto Label;
    }
}

Label:
func();
```

Чем черевато использование goto в данном случае? Какие плюсы и минусы у этого оператора?

Comment: @Cactus почему?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/271131/

Comment: Стив Макконнелл уделил дюжину страниц этому вопросу в своей книге [Совершенный код](https://www.bsuir.by/m/12_100229_1_98218.pdf). 389 - 401. Рекомендую прочитать если не всю книгу, то хотя бы их